# Remove decimal places for my crystal reports string variable

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a string filed in my crystal report with a value of 1,800.667. But I want to display only 1,800 in my report. I am using below formula but that's not working. Any ideas?

```
totext(tonumber({variable1}),0,"")
```

Comment: `not working` any error?

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
ToText( ToNumber({variable1}), "#" )
```

Answer (score -2):

```
IF int({FieldName})<>{FieldName}then
2
else 
0
```